# Plotting embeddings from graph neural network in pytorch geometric

Tags: matplotlib, graph, deep-learning, pytorch, pytorch-geometric

If I am doing a link prediction task, how would I gather the final embeddings? If I am using LinkNeighborSampling, it takes a subset of the graph and performs message passing each batch. But from what I understand, it is impossible to gather embeddings from each batch and then combine them to get all the embeddings.

The only way I can think is to only plot a single batch.

Comment: Could provide a minimal code example to illustrate your problem?